# Why WPF's dataGrid's selectedItem remains null after assigned dataRow?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to programatically select newly added row on dataGrid. No fancy stuff, no MVVM, just simple code behind.

SelectedItem remains null no matter what I do - I have no clue what the heck is wrong with this.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //source for dataGrid
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("one", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("two", typeof(string));

            //add new row
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "uno";
            dr[1] = "dos";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //select new row
            dataGrid.SelectedItem = dr;
            //here dataGrid.SelectedItem is still null, no row selected

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dr doesn't yet exists in rows of dataGrid, add dt as itemssource and then set selected row
..

selected row is actually the object in grid.Items and if you want to set it as selected make sure there referential equality is satisfied..

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that items of `DataView` are of [`DataRowView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx) type and you're trying to set `SelectedItem` to an instance of `DataRow`. Instead of setting `SelectedItem` you can set `SelectedIndex`. Another thing is that setting selected properties needs to be done after you set `ItemsSource`

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
//at this point dataGrid.SelectedItem is an instance of DataRowView
```